# Submitting variables from an external Javascript file using JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have written a timer function and want to output the results on a separate page. The function works by having a JSP file call functions from a separate JS file and I've been trying to output the results to another screen as shown below:

Instruction in JSP file:

```
<button type="button" onclick="display()">Try it</button>
```

Instruction in JS file:

```
function display(){
        document.writeln(Timer);
    }
```

Whilst it works when I put the function in the JSP file, JSP apparently cannot execute document.write(ln) functions when it's in a separate file. I suspect this may be due to document.write()'s general unreliability as a function in general. Does anybody have any suggestions regarding how I can output external JS files onto another screen using JSP?

Answer (score -1):

Never mind. It turns out I just needed to refresh the simulation in order for it to read the code properly.